# If type of the value cannot be analyzed by looking into the bits, how does the machine know how the value should be manipulated?

Tags: c++, c

If type of the value cannot be analyzed or found out by looking into the bits(As written in books I have referred), how does the machine know how the value should be manipulated?

Comment: Everything needs to have some type in C++. That's how.

Comment: Eventually, deep enough, everything is just bit manipulation. *How* the bits are manipulated is controlled by the *type* of the value.

Comment: @Mgetz This has nothing to do with undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mgetz That's not what undefined behavior means. What you are talking about is called "implementation-defined", and it's still irrelevant to the question.

Comment: +1: This is actually not an unfair question, if you're not familiar with the way compilers work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C and C++ are *statically typed*, meaning that types are a compile-time concept. The compiler generates code to manipulate the bits in a manner appropriate to the type; the machine executes that code, and doesn't need to know anything about the type.

Comment: As a side note, I would like to add that it is possible to manipulate a set of bits with meaning in both cases, such as the Fast Inverse square root calculation used in Quake 3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root .  To summarize, a 32-bit float is manipulated as an integer for a few instructions because it was a faster method to get an approximate result.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler knows the type of every variable because you must declare each type. So the compiler generates the appropriate instructions for dealing with a variable of any particular type.

Answer (score 5):

The machine does not know: it's the compiler who knows. The same code for different types won't generate the same machine code.

Answer (score 2):

The C or C++ compiler knows.  So it knows to generate a MULTIPLY REAL vs a MULTIPLY UNSIGNED INTEGER vs. a MULTIPLY SIGNED INTEGER assembly instruction.  Sure, at our level, it's all just a `*`, but that's the primary objective of a compiler - to generate the assembly code necessary to yield our desired result.

Answer (score 2):

It is known to the compiler at compile time. When the program runs then this area of memory is manipulated according to the compiled code. This is why C++ and C# force defining types in source code.